# Error al mostrar elementos de navbar

Tags: javascript, next.js

que tal, estoy haciendo una pequeña practica para hacer un menú, pero en la pagina me muestra el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el componente que quiero mostrar:

--Header o Navbar

```
const Menu_List = [
```

{
text: "Home",
href: "/",
},
{
text: "About Us",
href: "/",
},
{
text: "News",
href: "/",
},
];
const Header = () => {
return (


<Link href={"/"} legacyBehavior>

Maqueta

```
    <div className="nav__menu-bar">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>

    <div className="nav__menu-list">
      {Menu_List.map((menu, idx) => {
        return (
          <div key={menu.text}>
            <Navitem {...menu} />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
 );
};
```

Y este es el componente para mostrar los items del menu:

```
const Navitem = (href, texto, active) => {
return (
<Link href = { href } legacyBehavior>
    <a className = { `nav__link ${active ? "active" : ""}` }>
        { texto }
    </a>
</Link>
 )
}
```